# CKEditor 5 Right to Left Support

Tags: 10, wysiwyg

The [CKEditor 5 docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html#:%7E:text=the%20localization%20guide.-,Right%E2%80%93to%E2%80%93left%20(RTL)%20languages%20support,%2C%20dropdowns%2C%20buttons%2C%20etc.) claim that version 5 comes with Right-to-left editing out the box. While I am sure this is true, I am struggling to get it to work as such in Drupal 10's version.

I have enabled Arabic on my English-by-default site and have enabled the Language toolbar option in for the text format. While editing the Arabic translation of the site (The UI is now RTL) and have my text in the Arabic language in the toolbar, it still writes LTR.

Is there an option I have overlooked to enable this support?

[image]

Comment: When editing the page what language is Drupal's UI? It looks like english based on the english "Body" "Text format". I think ckeditor will use whatever the UI language is rather than what you pick in the language dropdown

Comment: It's in Arabic (shown at the bottom of the screenshot). Both the URL and the default Drupal language dropdown are set to Arabic, and the screenshot is even after saving the node. The CKEditfor language is also set to Arabic for the written content. 
This is on a fresh install of D10 with only the English and Arabic languages installed.